# create database specific user in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, privileges

We are trying to create a user in Amazon Redshift which should only access a specific database. We know how to assign user to specific schema, but I want use public schema.

Till now we tried following commands:

To create user:

```
create user tt password 'tttt';
```

To create group:

```
create group report_group with user tt;
```

To grant access of database

```
grant select on  DATABASE demo TO tt;
```

but its not allowing running select query and fails with

> access denied to schema public

any suggestion in this.

Comment: Well, you didn't grant the select (and usage) privilege  on the schema public.

Comment: GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO GROUP report_group;


alter default privileges in schema public grant select on tables to group report_group;

Answer (score 1):

You need the below two grants to the user or the group

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO tt;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO tt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public
TO GROUP report_group;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO GROUP report_group;
```